# Jquery unbinding click() for an <a> tag

Tags: javascript, onclick, jquery

I have a simple

`<a id="eID" href="#showCSSOnlyModalElement">Element</a>`.

And I want to introduce some click functionality based on viewport/device size. However, unbinding this click event, disables the standard clickable functionality of the `<a>` element. I want to retain the default behavior of the `<a>` element for larger viewport/device.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  if ((document.documentElement.clientWidth < 700) || (screen.width < 700)){
    $('#eID').click(function(){//hideSomeOtherElements});
  }
  else {
    $('#eID').unbind('click');
  }
});
```

Testing:

1. Start with large desktop viewport. `<a>` works fine.
2. Resize to viewport = 500. The `<a>` and onClick functionality work fine.
3. Resize to large desktop viewport. The `<a>` does not work.

I have tried the .on/.off route also per jQuery documentation. Same result.

Please help.

Comment: One problem with that code is that you attach the handler multiple times (every time the user resizes the window and it's above your limits). But that doesn't explain the actual symptom you described, because they should all get removed by your `$('#eID').unbind('click');` code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I probably wouldn't bind/unbind, I'd just check when the click occurs:

```
$("#eID").click(function(e) {
  if ((document.documentElement.clientWidth < 700) || (screen.width < 700)){
    // Do something for smaller viewports

    e.preventDefault(); // Prevents default behavior of click
                        // You can also use `e.stopPropagation()` to
                        // stop the event propagating, or use
                        // `return false` to do both.
  }
  else {
    // Don't do anything, allow default behavior of click
    // (You probably don't need the `else` at all, it's just to make
    // clear you're not doing anything here.)
  }
});
```

This is not only simpler, but easier to debug.

Comment: Your suggestion is probably a better way to structure the code. But my main problem is still unresolved. Let's say you start by loading the page with a smaller viewport. And consequently there will be a binding of the click event (and also the e.preventDefault()). Next, resize the same window to a larger viewport. The onClick will still behave as per the binding/functionality defined for a smaller viewport.

Comment: @KayaToast: That's why I'm saying don't vary the binding, vary what you do when the click occurs. Example: http://jsbin.com/OSigUdO/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/OSigUdO/1/edit).

Comment: It took sometime for me to see the light, but now I do :-) ... It makes sense (and works) - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function callback {
    ...
}
$('#eID').bind('click', callback);
$('#eID').unbind('click', callback);
```

The jQuery API recommends that you specify the callback otherwise bad things could happen.

Comment: The OP's code would unbind the handlers they were binding. Also, if you're going to say the API docs recommend something, *quote* them and link to the source of that quote.